# What does the y-axis in this Frequency vs Residuals graph mean?

Tags: residuals, frequency

[image]

(Asner et al 2013)

This is on a paper I'm reading, and I get the residuals part, but I'm not so sure on what the frequency means. Can someone please explain these graphs?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The units on the vertical axes are *relative* frequencies *per unit of $x.$*** That is, these plots are *histograms.*  They represent relative frequency in terms of *areas* under the curve rather than by heights of the curve.

**The way you can tell is that the areas under all the graphs are unity.**  A quick visual check is to approximate one of these graphs as a triangle.  For instance, the red Barro Colorado graph has a base of approximately $40 - (-75)=115$ and a height of $0.015,$ so its area must be close to $(1/2)\times 115\times 0.015 \approx 0.86,$ which is practically $1$ for such a rough estimate.  The other graphs similarly check out.

According to the units calculus, then, the units on the vertical axes must be

```
(relative frequency) / (Mg C/Ha) = Ha / (Mg C)
```

because relative frequencies are unitless.

Comment: Generally histograms are plots with discretization of the x-axis with bars indicating counts in categories. I would have thought these plots were densities, i.e. the continuous counterpart of histograms. (I make this comment/question with full understanding that you are a far better statistician than I, so I'm really asking for terminological clarification

Comment: @DWin The commonest, and most useful, definition of a histogram is the one I gave rather than the one you have stated.  But you have correctly pointed to the essence of the idea: the reason for insisting that histograms of finite amounts of data depict relative frequencies by area (instead of height) is that these are then *identical* to density plots of continuous distributions.

Comment: You're saying that histograms are typically defined as plots of densities rather than frequencies? Do I need to go back to my answers on StackOverflow and correct all my answrs and comments on this matter <g>.

Comment: @DWin The key distinction is not *what* a histogram shows, but *how* it shows it.  Histograms depict a quantity in terms of area rather than height.

Comment: But there is a distinction between density histograms and frequency histograms.